# can't run gdb on ubuntu: Could not find platform independent libraries

Tags: c, ubuntu, gdb

Can't run 'gdb ./a.out' or even 'gdb --help' without getting:

```
$ gdb ./a.out 
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS is up to date.  Works in 'root'.  I'd rather not hardcode a $PYTHONHOME location.  Any hints appreciated.  Baffled.

update: when I set $PYTHONHOME I get:

```
$ PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib/python2.7 gdb ./a.out 
ImportError: No module named site
```

update: I do have python-dev installed for native module creation.

Thx

Comment: Does setting $PYTHONHOME help?  You don't have to hard-code it just to try it: `PYTHONHOME=/path/to/whatever gdb ./a.out`  will set this variable just for this command.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, the first 3 errors go away when I do that, updating my post...

Answer (score 1):

Could you be running into this [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=488478)?  Do you have `python` *and* `python-libs` installed?

Comment: yes, I do have python-libs and python-dev installed for swig stuff.  It isn't clear to me the upstream connections to redhat but it may be that bug.  thx!